# unreported IOException even though in try-catch block and throws Exception

Tags: java, ioexception

My code has unreported IOExceptions even though I have it in a try-catch block and at the method name I have throws IOException

```
public static void addStudent() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Add Details");
        frame.setSize(350, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(
          JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JTextField tf1 = new JTextField("Input Student's name here", 25);
        final JTextField tf2 = new JTextField("Input Student's ID number here", 25);
        final JTextField tf3 = new JTextField("Input Student's Email Address here", 25);
        final JTextField tf4 = new JTextField("Input Student's address here", 25);
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        JButton back = new JButton("Back");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(tf1);
        panel.add(tf2);
        panel.add(tf3);
        panel.add(tf4);
        panel.add(submit);
        panel.add(back);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                    {
                        String name = tf1.getText();
                        String ID = tf2.getText();
                        String email = tf3.getText();
                        String address = tf4.getText();
                        String fileName = ID + "Details.csv";
                        File file = new File(fileName);
                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName); 
                        name = name.concat(",");
                        ID = ID.concat(",");
                        email = email.concat(",");
                        address = address.concat(",");
                        fw.write(name);
                        fw.write(ID);
                        fw.write(email);
                        fw.write(address);
                        fw.close();
                    }
                });


    back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                    frame.dispose();
                    GUI.AdminGUI();
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
}
```

Can anyone see why this is happening? I don't understand why the exception is being thrown

Comment: I'm quite new to programming so could you tell me how it looks weird, it would be much appreciated. Thanks for the advice. I'll try it

Comment: Your code has un-*handled* IOExceptions. Don't just guess at what the compiler said. Quote it accurately. Read it accurately. It tells you the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the `try/catch` block inside the `actioPerformed()`. I think you're catch may not be within the scope of the `actionPerformed()`

```
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        try {
             String name = tf1.getText();
             String ID = tf2.getText();
             String email = tf3.getText();
             String address = tf4.getText();
             String fileName = ID + "Details.csv";
             File file = new File(fileName);
             FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName); 
             name = name.concat(",");
             ID = ID.concat(",");
             email = email.concat(",");
             address = address.concat(",");
             fw.write(name);
             fw.write(ID);
             fw.write(email);
             fw.write(address);
             fw.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
             ex .printStackTrace();
             System.exit(0);
        }          
    }
});
```

If you do this, you don't need to the `addStudent()` to throw any exception and you don't need its `try/catch` block.

Comment: I did what you said and I get this error : error: cannot find symbol fw.close();

Comment: Just put it back at the bottom of the `try` where you had it, and get rid of the `finally` block. If you put in the `finally`, it wouldn't be in the scope. Sorry. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get an error in writing Java code, whether it happens when you try to *compile* or *run* the code, always take note of specifically where the error happens (e.g. the line number, which method(s) this happens in).  And share it with the people you ask for help.

My best guess is that java is complaining because your `addStudent` method throws `Exception` and the part elsewhere in your code that uses `addStudent` (likely your `main` method) doesn't handle this possible `Exception` that is thrown.