# try catch and throw - still get "unreported exception"

Tags: java, exception, netbeans

About the Java code below, NetBeans complains about the `throw` statement, stating there is an "unreported exception `IOException`", even though I am already catching it...

```
public class MyClass {
    
    public static java.util.Properties properties = new java.util.Properties();
    static {
        try {
            properties.load(new java.io.FileInputStream("my.properties"));
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException somethingbad) {
            throw somethingbad;
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace
`throw somethingbad;`
with
`;`
there is no complaining. I want to understand why this is and how to properly handle it. I want the program simply to stop if there is such exception, hence why I re-throw it.

I checked the answers to this question [unreported IOException even though in try-catch block and throws Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185009/unreported-ioexception-even-though-in-try-catch-block-and-throws-exception) but they did not enlighten me.

This class is standing alone for now. No other class is referencing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Java there are two types of Exceptions :**

> 1- Checked Exceptions
>
> 2- Unchecked Exceptions

**Handle** : using a try catch block : the line that may cause the exception should be in the try block , the catch block run when the exception thrown .

**Declare** : when declaring a method that can cause an Exception , you can add the syntax : throws Exception_Class_Name to inform the caller that this method may contain a code that can probably throw an Exception of type Exception_Class_Name.

---

*Unchecked Exceptions* dont cause a problem because they are not required to be handled or declared , but there is not problem if you handle or declare.

*Checked Exceptions* are required to be **Handled** Or **declared** (you can handle and declare in the same time).

Looking at your example you have an exception of type IOException named "*somethingbad*"  , in java code any line that throw surely a *Checked Exception* must be handled or declared , so the line :

```
    throw somethingbad;
```

must be handled or declared , here your line is inside a static block , we can declare Exception when talking about a code inside a methods, so here you are required to handle the *Exception* using a try catch block , *putting your line inside the try and writing a catch block that can catch the exact type or a supertype of this check Exception*, if you need that your program stop excecution you can simply throw an *Unchecked Exception* ( `RuntimeException` for example).

**Handling the IOEXception :**

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class MyClass {

    public static java.util.Properties properties = new java.util.Properties();
    static {
        try {
            properties.load(new java.io.FileInputStream("my.properties"));
        } catch (IOException somethingbad) {
            try {
                throw somethingbad;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();    

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Throwing an Unchecked Exception :**

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class MyClass {

    public static java.util.Properties properties = new java.util.Properties();
    static {
        try {
            properties.load(new java.io.FileInputStream("my.properties"));
        } catch (IOException somethingbad) {
            throw new RuntimeException(somethingbad.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the 1st solution example, do you mean that first we catch a compile-time exception and second we catch a run-time one (hence the 2 try-catch blocks)?

Comment: @JoãoSilva : in the first example : catching the CheckedException allow the code to compile , if you dont write the catch IOException the code will not compile. In the second example : if you need just to make your program stop execution you can throw an UncheckedException of type Runtime , you can write throw new Runtime Exception without putting it inside a try catch block and it will work and stop the execution of the program.

Comment: **Under no circumstances** should code contain an empty `catch` block.  There is never a valid reason for doing that.  Your second example completely discards the original IOException’s stack trace, making it impossible for a developer to determine what went wrong;  writing `throw new RuntimeException(e);` would preserve the original exception’s information.

Comment: @VGR Just a simple example to give Joao idea about Exceptions types , meaning of handle and declare , I added .getMessage() call to give information about the original exception informations

Comment: But the original IOException’s stack trace is gone.  The developer won’t be able to determine whether the problem occurred opening the FileInputStream or parsing the file content as properties.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is `rethrowing` same exception back to caller of your static block.

As per [Java specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3), it is compile time error if static block throws checked exception class.

In your case, since you are using `FileInputStream` which eventually needs to handle with either `FileNotFoundException` or `IOException` & that is reason when you `rethrow` checked `IOException` it gives you compile time error.
If you really want to stop your execution after this exception occur, then simply you can print stacktrace within your code block:

```
class MyClass {
    
    public static java.util.Properties properties = new java.util.Properties();
    static {
        try {
            properties.load(new java.io.FileInputStream("my.properties"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace(); //just to give info why exception occurred.
        }
    }
}
```